# Driving moving van towing car Nashville to salt lake best route?...

Tags: road-trips

Driving moving van and towing car August.  To salt lake from Nashville.  Recommendations for time and safety.  Worried about me roads in the moving van and tow but would like a fun place to stop. Any fun western towns that 9 year old boy would enjoy ?...

Answer (score 1):

The obvious route is straight across on I-80, plenty of motels just off the highway that would have fairly easy parking for your truck and trailer.  But it does not go past much in the way of well known tourist stops.  You could visit AAA and check out their state by state guides for off the beaten path possibilities.

Drive time is about 24 hours or so IN A CAR.  But driving a U-Haul truck with car trailer does not allow you to motor at the speed limit like cars do.  You are looking at four days to do it comfortably, potentially more depending on how long you want to stop and let your son explore.

Driving the U-Haul truck is not that difficult, but you have to constantly remind yourself of its size and length.  And when descending out of mountains (if you choose a route that crosses bigger ones) use your transmission to control speed, not only your brakes.  Also when buying gas, going to a station that markets itself as a truck stop is good, because they will have spaced their gas pumps to allow bigger trucks to maneuver (I have seen my fair share of U-Hauls and big RVs have difficulty filling up in a car oriented gas station).

Comment: Filling up at truckstops is good advice. Certain truckstops (like Flying J) often have dedicated RV fuel islands which can be used here.